# Print to file from MPFR

Tags: c++, fstream, mpfr

I want to print the result of a calculation using `MPFR` to file but I don't know how. `MPFR` is used to do floating point operations with high accuracy. To print an `mpfr_t` number you use the function:

`size_t mpfr_out_str (FILE *stream, int base, size t n, mpfr t op, mp rnd t rnd)`

I guess my problem is that I don't understand `FILE*` objects and how they are related to `fstream` objects.

If I change `my_file` in the `mpfr_out_str` line to `stdout` then the number will print to the screen as I'd hoped but I don't know how to get it into the file.

```
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   mpfr_t x;
   mpfr_init(x);
   mpfr_set_d(x, 1, MPFR_RNDN);

   ofstream my_file;
   my_file.open("output.txt");
   mpfr_out_str(my_file, 2, 0, x, MPFR_RNDN);
   my_file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the std::ostream methods with mpfr functions like mpfr_as_printf or mpfr_get_str. It however requires an additional string allocation.

```
  #include <mpfr.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  using namespace std;
  int main() {
     mpfr_t x;
     mpfr_init(x);
     mpfr_set_d(x, 1, MPFR_RNDN);

     ofstream my_file;
     my_file.open("output.txt");

     char* outString = NULL;
     mpfr_asprintf(&outString, "%RNb", x);
     my_file << outString;
     mpfr_free_str(outString);
     my_file.close();

     mpfr_clear(x);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After not much work I found this to replace the bottom 4 lines of code:

```
FILE* my_file;
my_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");
mpfr_out_str(my_file, 2, 0, x, MPFR_RNDN);
fclose(my_file);
```